# How do I make a lightning:button expand horizontally to fill a div?

Tags: slds, page-layout, size, lightning-button

Is there any way to make a lightning:button expand horizontally until it fills the boundaries of its div? I've been trying for ages but nothing I try works, is it possible or is salesforce still working on that functionality? Here's what I'm trying/something to work with:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded-medium">
        <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" pullToBoundary="small">
                <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">

                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="TEST" iconName="utility:up" iconPosition="right"/>

                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried CSS stuff too but it won't work either, pretty much out of ideas at this point. Would appreciate any advice

CSS stuff:

.THIS.widebutton {

```
display: block;
margin: 10px 0;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
```

}

still a n00b when it comes to salesforce css styling, I added class="widebutton" to the lightning:button but that may have been the wrong way to do it.

Comment: post everything you've tried using CSS to avoid suggesting things you have already tried. Additionally, what div are you trying to fully expand the button in? Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to expand the button to the topmost div, '<div style="width:200px;">'. I'm actually building a component that I will use elsewhere all over the place, and need the button to expand to fill whatever container I put the component in. The <div style="width:200px;"> is just for testing,  hopefully I'll be able to change/remove it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything @glls said is correct.  This is to just help point out the areas where you might consider some changes...

```
<div style="width:200px;"> //This makes the max width of everything inside 200px.
  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded-medium">
    <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" pullToBoundary="small">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">

                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="TEST" iconName="utility:up" iconPosition="right"/>

            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will give you the ability to be more flexible.

```
<div style="width: 50%; min-width: 200px; max-width: 400px;"> //Make this auto, or a percentage and it will scale with the screen.  
                                                              //You can also use min-width and max-width...
  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_pull-padded-medium">
    <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" pullToBoundary="small">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">

                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="TEST" iconName="utility:up" iconPosition="right"/>

            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For your CSS:

```
.THIS.widebutton {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%; // this will make it fill the width available to it. Which is currently 200px.
    background-color: red;
}
```

Try something like this CSS:

```
.THIS.widebutton {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 96%;
    min-width: 140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; //the margin left and right auto make the display block center.
    background-color: red;
}
```

Again, @glls is correct... and if you wanted to fill everything in a top level container, you would have to have the button outside of divs that have limitations...

Comment: Success! As per usual less is more, all it took was '.THIS .wide {
    
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    min-width: 120px;
}' in the CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You basically are putting your button in a box within another box that is in a bigger box, then you are telling your button to expand to its fullest within the smallest box.

[image]

Either take your button out of the smallest box, aka div and or change the display property value, property values can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: I figured there was some kind of scope problem, but which divs are limiting the scope? are the slds-col and slds-grid divs getting in the way/stopping the button from expanding to fill the 200px div? thanks for your help btw, I suck at styling

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzckbNyqfc

Comment: lol so true, I'll keep you posted, think I'm getting closer